# Rails. Send create notification when custom form field param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How to send email if a custom form field filled?

```
   def create
    @act = Act.new(act_params)     
    respond_to do |format|
      if @act.save 
        ModelMailer.new_act_notification(@act).deliver_later if customer_id == '617'
        format.html { redirect_to @act, notice: 'Act was successfully created.' }       
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set the variable customer_id, this won't work. I think what you want is this:

```
ModelMailer.new_act_notification(@act).deliver_later if @act.customer_id == 617
```

I assume that when you say 'custom form field param', you mean the customer_id parameter of the object in `@act`.